# How to remove gaps in a time series data chart when data is not available in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm using Flex for charting time series data. the data range is from 2002 to 2009, however the data is not available for some periods of time (i.e from 4/2004 to 8/2005). The following lines show the tags I'm using for the chart:

```
<mx:Canvas id="cp" backgroundColor="#ffffff" fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="12" color="#093A89" fontWeight="bold" width="100%" height="100%" alpha="1" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:LineChart id="cChart"  showDataTips="true" paddingRight="40" paddingLeft="30" width="100%" height="85%">
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis id="linearAxis" baseAtZero="false" title="{parameterLabel}" minorInterval="0.5" interval="1.0"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{linearAxis}" fontSize="10">
            <mx:axisStroke>
                <mx:SolidColorStroke weight="6" color="#BBCCDD" alpha="1" caps="square"/>
            </mx:axisStroke>                    
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis id="ca" minimum="{sDate}" maximum="{eDate}" title="Date" dataUnits="days" dataInterval="1" labelUnits="days"/> 
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{ca}" canDropLabels="true" fontSize="10" labelRotation="45">         
            <mx:axisStroke>
                <mx:SolidColorStroke weight="6" color="#BBCCDD" alpha="1" caps="square"/>
            </mx:axisStroke>                    
        </mx:AxisRenderer>              
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries id="l1" visible="false"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
<mx:Legend id="mylgn" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="32"/>
<s:Label id="lblChart1" text="{dataType} {parameterLabel} at {streamLabel}" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="20"/>
<s:Label id="lblChart2" text="{optionalText}" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="5"/>
```

The following image illustrates the chart created by the above code:
[image]

As you can see there are gaps for the intervals with no data. Is there any way to remove/cut the intervals with no data? What is the best practice for this type of data?

Any thoughts or recommendation would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished via an adapter to your `dataProvider`.

To show a horizontal line between missing samples, you must add an additional sample to your data provider with value equal to the last sample.

If you had time series data of:

```
timestamp    value
4/2004       3
8/2005       23
```

You would add an additional sample immediately before 8/2005 equal to the previous value of 3.

```
timestamp    value
4/2004       3
7/2005       3 <-- insert sample
8/2005       23
```

Instead of interpolating between values 3 and 23, a flat horizontal line is displayed.

**Sample data model**

```
package
{
    public class TrendData
    {
        public var timestamp:Date;
        public var value:Number;
    }
}
```

**Static adapter utility**

```
package
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayList;

    public class TimeSeriesDataAdapter
    {

        public static function interpolate(data:ArrayList):ArrayList
        {
            var set:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
            var timespan:Number;

            // add first sample:
            set.addItem(data[0]);

            for (var i:uint = 1; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                // measure timestamp between current sample and last sample
                timespan = TrendData(data[i]).timestamp.time - TrendData(data[i-1]).timestamp.time;

                // if the timespan is greater than desired range (1-day), add a sample
                if(timespan >= 86400000)
                {
                    var trendData:TrendData = new TrendData();

                    // set timestamp just before sample
                    trendData.timestamp = new Date(TrendData(data[i]).timestamp.time - 1);

                    // set value to previous value
                    trendData.value = TrendData(data[i-1]).value;

                    set.addItem(trendData);
                }

                set.addItem(data[i]);
            }

            return set;
        }

    }
}
```

**Data Visualization implementation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            [Bindable]
            [ArrayElementType("TrendData")]
            public var data:ArrayList
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:LineChart dataProvider="{TimeSeriesDataAdapter.interpolate(data)}" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you Jason for your answer in great detail. I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie in Flex. I never created a class/package by my own. When I add the classes in my code, I get the error "packages must not be nested". Would you please let me know Where the right place is to add the packages?

Comment: OK Jason. I just created the classes by using File->New->ActionScript Class in a separate file. I'm not sure if it is the best way, but it works for me. I had to tweak your code a little bit to make it suitable for my application. I'm going to explain it in another answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jason's answer to fix the gap issue in my charts. However to make the code suitable for my application, I applied the following changes. 
1- I replaced ArryList to ArrayCollection
2- I didn't use the TrendData class
3- Since my date filed is string, I had to convert it to date first
4- I considered 7 days or more as a gap
5- I had to sort my ArrayCollection before creating the excessive points.

The following shows my version of the TimeSeriesDataAdapter.interpolate function:

```
 public static function interpolate(data:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection
 {
      var set:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
      var timespan:Number;
      var oneDayTime:Number = 86400000; // 1000*60*60*24 = 1 day
      for (var j:uint = 1; j < data.length; j++)
      {
           // measure timestamp between current sample and last sample
           data[j].formattedDate  = DateField.stringToDate(data[j].Date,"MM/DD/YYYY");
           data[j].time  = data[j].formattedDate.time;
      }
      var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField(); 
      dataSortField.name = "time"; 
      var numericDataSort:Sort = new Sort(); 
      numericDataSort.fields = [dataSortField]; 
      data.sort = numericDataSort; 
      data.refresh(); 
      // add first sample:
      set.addItem(data[0]);
      for (var i:uint = 1; i < data.length; i++)
      {
           // measure timestamp between current sample and last sample
           timespan = data[i].time - data[i-1].time;
           // if the timespan is greater than desired range (7-days), add a sample
           if(timespan >= oneDayTime*7) 
           {
                var trendData:Object = new Object();
                var timestamp:Date = new Date();
                trendData = data[i-1];
                // set timestamp just before sample
                timestamp.time = data[i].time - 1;
                trendData.Date = DateField.dateToString(timestamp,"MM/DD/YYYY");
                set.addItem(trendData);
           }
           set.addItem(data[i]);
      }
      return set;
 }
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of the horizontal lines when the data is not available, simple add "trendData.Value = NaN;" line before "set.addItem(trendData);"